# Google map activity cannot run when open twice android? My program is how to get closest distance between many marker

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm developer google android programming, Now my project is how to get closest distance between many marker on google maps. When the application  run first after compile, it works fine. But after i close the  application and run again suddenly application is stop. 
 This is my code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dispel;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> mMarkerPoints=null; 
    SupportMapFragment fm;
    ImageView iv;
    String atmhasil=null;
    JSONArray jArray;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String gps_mode=null;
    Polyline poliline=null;
    Boolean end_value;
    LatLng dest;
    Location location;
    Byte status_location;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           gpson();

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
             fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            //globalvariable ak= new globalvariable();

                if(fm==null){
                    fm.setRetainInstance(true);
                        }else{

                     googleMap = fm.getMap();                   
                }






            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 35000, 0, this);
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


            // Getting Current Location

             location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
             gps_mode="yes";
            new download_database().execute("atm.php");


        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        // Showing the current location in Google Map


        // tvLocation.setText(latitude + " dan " + longitude);
        if (gps_mode != null)
        {
            //poliline.remove();
            //poliline=null;

     choose_route csr=  new choose_route(latLng, mMarkerPoints);
     csr.execute();
   /*  try
     {
  String coba= csr.get();
    //txtv.setText("" + coba + "");
     } catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
    //TextView txtv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

    // String cob =   csr.get();

        String url = getDirectionsUrl(latLng, dest);                
        DirectionJsonPharser _distance= new DirectionJsonPharser();
        txtv.setText(_distance.distance_count(url));


        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);*/}
        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onResume()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onResume();
         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, this);
          gps_mode="yes";

    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onStop()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onDestroy()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();


    }

    public void gpson(){
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
              !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
          // Build the alert dialog
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setTitle("Informasi!");
          builder.setMessage("Tolong Nyalakan GPS Anda.");
          builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

            }
          });
          Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
          alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
          alertDialog.show();}

    }

        public void callatm(){
            globalvariable ak= new globalvariable();
            atmhasil=ak.koneksi("atm.php","");
            try{
                jArray= new JSONArray(atmhasil);
                JSONObject json_data=null;
                for (int i=0;i< jArray.length();i++)
                {
                    json_data=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    double lati= Double.parseDouble(json_data.getString("l1"));
                    double lang= Double.parseDouble(json_data.getString("l2"));
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, lang)).title(json_data.getString("nm")));

                }
            }catch(Exception ex){

            }


        }
        private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

            // Origin of route
            String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

            // Destination of route
            String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

            return url;
        }
        private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            // Downloading data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

                // For storing data from web service
                String data = "";

                try{
                    // Fetching the data from web service
                    data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                }
                return data;
            }

            // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
            // doInBackground()
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

                // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
                parserTask.execute(result);
            }
        }
        private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
            }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return data;
        }



        private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

            // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

                JSONObject jObject;
                List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
                 try{
                    jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                    DirectionJsonPharser parser = new DirectionJsonPharser();

                    // Starts parsing data
                    routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                return routes;
            }

            // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {

                ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
                PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

                    if(poliline != null)
                    {

                        poliline.remove();
                        poliline=null;
                    }


                // Traversing through all the routes
                for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                    // Fetching i-th route
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                    // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                    for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                        HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                        points.add(position);
                    }

                    // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                    lineOptions.addAll(points);
                    lineOptions.width(5);
                    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                }

                // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
                //googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
              poliline=  googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            }
        }
        // Async Data atm
          private class download_database extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

                /* (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
                 */
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    globalvariable ak= new globalvariable();
                    atmhasil=ak.koneksi(params[0],"");

                    return atmhasil;
                }

                /* (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
                 */
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{

                        jArray= new JSONArray(result);
                        JSONObject json_data=null;

                        mMarkerPoints= new ArrayList<LatLng>();

                        for (int i=0;i< jArray.length();i++)
                        {
                            json_data=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            double lati= Double.parseDouble(json_data.getString("l1"));
                            //tvloc.setText(""+ lati + "" );
                            double lang= Double.parseDouble(json_data.getString("l2"));
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, lang)).title(json_data.getString("nm")));
                            mMarkerPoints.add(new LatLng(lati, lang));
                        }
                        if(location!=null){

                            onLocationChanged(location);


                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
                }

                /* (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
                 */
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }
          }
          private class choose_route extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<LatLng>, Void, String>{

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
             */
              LatLng firs_point;
              ArrayList<LatLng> atm_sync;

              public choose_route(LatLng firs_point, ArrayList<LatLng> atm_sync){
                 this.firs_point=firs_point;
                this.atm_sync=atm_sync;
              }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<LatLng>... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ArrayList<LatLng> atmarray= new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                atmarray=atm_sync;
                 final Integer[] idx=new Integer[atmarray.size()] ;
                 final double[] data=new double[atmarray.size()] ;
                for (int i=0; i< atmarray.size();i++)
                {

                    /*DirectionJsonPharser _distance= new DirectionJsonPharser();
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(firs_point, atmarray.get(i) );*/              
                    //txtv.setText(_distance.distance_count(url));

                    idx[i]=i;
                    data[i]=(double) distance_AtoB(firs_point, atmarray.get(i));
                /*  data[i]= Double.parseDouble(_distance.distance_count(url));*/
                }



                Arrays.sort(idx, new Comparator<Integer>() {
                    @Override public int compare(final Integer o1, final Integer o2) {
                        return Double.compare(data[o1], data[o2]);
                    }
                });

                globalvariable ak= new globalvariable();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), idx[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                atmhasil=ak.koneksi("atm.php","" + idx[0] + "");



                return atmhasil ;
            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
             */
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                try{
                    jArray= new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject json_data=null;
                    for (int i=0;i< jArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        json_data=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        double lati= Double.parseDouble(json_data.getString("l1"));
                        double lang= Double.parseDouble(json_data.getString("l2"));
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, lang)).title(json_data.getString("nm")));
                        dest= new LatLng(lati, lang);
                    }

                    TextView txtv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(firs_point, dest);                

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);

                }catch(Exception ex){
                /*  TextView txtv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
                    txtv.setText("" + ex.toString() +"");*/
                }



            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
             */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

          }


          private float distance_AtoB(LatLng Apoint,LatLng Bpoint){
              Location locationA = new Location("point A");

              locationA.setLatitude(Apoint.latitude);
              locationA.setLongitude(Apoint.longitude);

              Location locationB = new Location("point B");

              locationB.setLatitude(Bpoint.latitude);
              locationB.setLongitude(Bpoint.longitude);

              float distance_point = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
              return distance_point;
          }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
                {  
                    //do whatever you want the 'Back' button to do  
                    //as an example the 'Back' button is set to start a new Activity named 'NewActivity'  
                 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);


                 Intent inte= new Intent(this,Log_in.class);
                   startActivity(inte);

                   finish();
                }  
                return true; 
        }



}
```

This is Error log Cat

```
05-11 15:23:46.050: W/dalvikvm(11959): threadid=29: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at com.example.dispel.MainActivity$choose_route.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:516)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at com.example.dispel.MainActivity$choose_route.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-11 15:23:46.060: E/AndroidRuntime(11959):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you please post the Logcat when error is occuring..

Comment: @Lal yes i have include my log cat in my question. Please help me... :'(

Comment: What is line no 516 in MainActivity???

Comment: @Lal      final Integer[] idx=new Integer[atmarray.size()] ;

Comment: Check if there is value for `atmarray.size()` before line no 516

Comment: @Lal The value from mMakerpoints is null how to fix that, but if first i run this application mMarkerpoints is not null.

Comment: In which class is mMarkerpoints null???I cant find it out in your code..Please tell me the exact location..

Comment: @Lal at class Async with name download_database

Comment: You are adding the points in onPostExecute(),right???Are you sure the points are added to that??

Comment: @Lal yes... When i run application the first work's well, the value is appear. but When application close and i open again . the value is null.

Comment: Remove the try catch and see what is the exact error occuring there..

Comment: @Lal Thank's but i had finish my problem. Thank you for your answer.